# What is meant by  htmlencode and urlencode?

Tags: character-encoding, urlencode, html-encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Url Encode and HTML encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812473/difference-between-url-encode-and-html-encode)

What does HTMLEncode mean and how do I use it?

What does URLEncode mean and how is it different from HTMLEncode?