# "&amp" character from api url not saved to mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am working on an application that involves getting the entire page content from a page using javascript and dumping the html to the database.On the page I have various components that will be parsed and stored using a `ajax` request.I do it like this.

```
 function saveContent(){    
    var $getContent = $('#mainWrap').clone();
    $getContent.find('.textBox, .pictureBox').removeAttr('id');
    var saveContent  = $getContent.wrap('<div></div>').html();
    var getBodyStyle=$('body').attr('style');
    var auto="auto";
    $.ajax({
        url:"save.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"text",
        data:"txtComp="+saveContent+"&auto="+auto+"&pageId="+pageId+"&webId="+webId+"&userId="+userId+"&bodyStyle="+getBodyStyle,
        success:function(data){
            var options = {"text":data,"layout":"topCenter","type":"success","animateOpen": {"opacity": "show"}};
            setTimeout(function(){noty(options)}, 1000);
            //$('#draftMsg').html(data).fadeIn(500);
        }
    }); 
 }
```

Now I have social media components like facebook,twitter.When I try to save the facebook component it is not save entirely as it contains some parameters that are present in the script with '&amp'.

```
    <div style="z-index: 1001; height: 560px; width: 413px; top: -20px; left: 121.5px;" id="com-IADDFSGNHLU7WNR3WM2KC3I8DA2DOIC6" class="facebookBox contentBox boxStyle">
    <div class="blankDiv"></div>
    <iframe class="facebookBoxObject" allowtransparency="true" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 560px; width: 413px;" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?api_key=117096311791424&amp;locale=en_US&amp;height=560&amp;header=true&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=true&amp;width=413&amp;href=http://www.facebook.com/cbil360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
   </div>
```

The above is the content I want to store to the database and I get it when I say `console.log` but in the database it stores only the below content

```
 <div style="z-index: 1001; height: 388px; width: 283px; top: -20px; left: 120.5px;" id="com-IADDFSGNHLU7WNR3WM2KC3I8DA2DOIC6" class="facebookBox contentBox boxStyle">
    <div class="blankDiv"></div><iframe class="facebookBoxObject" allowtransparency="true" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 388px; width: 283px;" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?api_key=117096311791424
```

It breaks after the `api_key` parameter as it has & after that.I am not asure as I don't get any error for this.Tried to debug but,not to a conclusion yet.
Please correct where am I going wrong.

**Update:** The query I am using is

```
$query = "insert into tbl_revision (userId,revisionContent,webId,pageId,status,saveType,dateAdded) values ('".$_SESSION['UserId']."','$revisionContent','$webId','$pageId','$status','$saveType','$toDate')"
```

Comment: Can you post your PHP? I'm guessing it has to do with your query or method of executing the query.

Comment: You don't escape the GET parameters. Perhaps you should. The fact the content is terminated at the & indicates that.

Comment: I have updated the question with the query.I think the query is right as I can save rest of the components.The field in the database is marked as `varchar` if that might make a difference.

Comment: Try changing the `data` field in your ajax call to use json format. eg: data: `{txtComp: saveContent, auto: auto, pageId: pageId}`

Comment: @JanDvorak by escape do yu mean I need to do `mysql_real_escape_strings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt that the problem is happening before the data reaches your backend. It's happening on the front end because you are including a `&` as a normal character in your query string which causes some confusion. What I recommend is either you **URL encode** your `saveContent` variable (**URL** encode not **HTML** encode).

```
encodeURIComponent(saveContent) //that will replace the & with it's corresponding url encoding
```

There is also another workaround, you could submit the ajax request fields using the json form provided by jquery $.ajax. An example of that would be

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"save.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"text",
        data:{txtComp: saveContent, auto: auto }, //etc
        success:function(data){
            var options = {"text":data,"layout":"topCenter","type":"success","animateOpen": {"opacity": "show"}};
            setTimeout(function(){noty(options)}, 1000);
            //$('#draftMsg').html(data).fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
```

---

I also recommend that you have a look on that question to know the difference betweeen URL Encoding and HTML Encoding

[Difference between Url Encode and HTML encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812473/difference-between-url-encode-and-html-encode)

Comment: The json part solved the issue.Will definitely have a look at the question. **One question** How does sending as json solve issue?Does normal string parameter blocks special characters?

Comment: It seems like jQuery does the url encoding for you when you use the json form. And logically, it won't be able to do the same when you use a flat string representation because it wouldn't be able to distinguish the field names and the field values.

Comment: Well will have a look at it!!Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to encoded the input string and decoded the output string with htmlentities and html_entity_decode?