# Unexpected Token on decodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, html, grails

I have a parameter in my grails view which I am passing to javascript code

```
<g:if test="${replacedString}">
    ${replacedString}
    <g:set var="replacedString" value="${replacedString}"/>
</g:if>
<script>
   var mydata = decodeURIComponent(${replacedString});
   console.log(mydata);
</script>
```

The replacedString value is being passed as an encoded string i.e: " appears as `&quot;`.
Due to this I have the method

```
decodeURIComponent
```

This is the string I'm trying to decode:

```
[{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;test1 &quot;,&quot;filenameAndPath&quot;:&quot;test1.pdf&quot;},{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;test file&quot;,&quot;filenameAndPath&quot;:&quot;test copy.pdf&quot;},{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;filenameAndPath&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;filenameAndPath&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]
```

This block of code keeps throwing the error `Syntax error: Unexpected token &`.
Am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **HTML** encoded.

use this trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript):-

```js
var encoded = "[{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;test1 &quot;,&quot;filenameAndPath&quot;:&quot;test1.pdf&quot;},{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;test file&quot;,&quot;filenameAndPath&quot;:&quot;test copy.pdf&quot;},{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;filenameAndPath&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;filenameAndPath&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]"

var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
elem.innerHTML = encoded;
var decoded = elem.value;

console.log(decoded);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812473/difference-between-url-encode-and-html-encode) for the differences in HTML and URL Encoding

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about the HTML vs URL encoding differences. Learnt something new :)